# Check if class exists without running into ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

In order to schedule the execution of a job, i get the name of a class as a string-input.
This class may be in one of two packages, but i don't know which one so i have to check this.

By now, i have two try-catch-blocks

```
Class<Job> clazz;
String className; //the above mentioned string, will be initialized

try {
    clazz = (Class<Job>) Class.forName("package.one." + className);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    try {
        clazz = (Class<Job>) Class.forName("package.two." + className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex1) {
      //some error handling code here, as the class is
      //in neither of the two packages
    }
}
```

For more packages this will get uglier and more unreadable. Furthermore, it is - for me - against the concept of exceptions, as exceptions should'nt be expected/used for flow-control!
Is there any way to rewrite this without the utilization of the `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: why don't u use a loop to check every package with a break if you don't reach exception?

Comment: or you can call recursively the same method in catch block with another classname

Comment: @wxyz, this won't be a (complete) solution, because he may be interested in a class, that is within some library. If there is a way to list all the loaded classes in the classpath at Runtime...

Comment: Why can't you expect fully qualified name instead just a class name ?. Who is giving class name ? instead they can pass fully qualified class name right ?

Comment: @Jayasagar the class name is stored in a database and it's not a small project. may have plenty of side-effects to switch to fully-qualified classnames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd stick to the `Class.forName` method for that.

You can store the class and package names in `Collection`s or `Set`s and loop through those elements. When you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, you just continue your search. If you don't get an exception, you exit the loop using `break`, as you have found the class you were looking for.

The reason I'd go for `Class.forName` is that it loads the class for you if it had not been already loaded by the VM. This is quite a powerful side effect.

It basically relieves you of the trouble of digging through the whole `CLASSPATH` and looking for class files to load in the VM and dealing with issues such as whether the class has already been loaded or not by the VM.

**EDIT:**

Jakob Jenkov has written some really great articles/tutorials on Java. I've found them extremely useful when dealing with reflection, class loaders and concurrency (some of the "hardest" aspects of Java).

[Here](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)'s a good article on the Java class loader by him, for if you still decide not to use `Class.forName`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable! +1 for the side effect on `Class.forName`.

Comment: Just noticed the comment on your question about class names being stored in a DB. The article in I've linked to in my response also covers class reloading and it might help you, should you need to reload classes in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the background information on class loading. In my case, this isn't neccessary. I think i will stick to `forName` and utilize a loop as you wrote and the other answers implemented.

Comment: The link in the post is broken as the page has moved, here's the working link: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Answer (score 4):

```
public Class<Job> getClass(String className) {
    String packages[] = { "package.one.", "package.two." };
    for (int j = 0; j < packages.length; j++) {
        try {
            return (Class<Job>) Class.forName(packages[j] + className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Package "+packages[j]+" is not worked");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Guava's Reflection](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained) utilities to get the [ClassInfo](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.ClassInfo.html) of every class loaded in the classpath.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(classLoader);
ImmutableSet<ClassInfo> set = classPath.getTopLevelClasses();
for (ClassInfo ci : set) {
    System.out.println(ci.getName());
}
```

In the loop you can implement your custom logic to load the class with the `className` you're providing.

Comment: Definitely a piece of cake, but including another third-party-lib will be a bit over the top for this specific project and problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I wouldn't worry about using the `ClassNotFoundException`. While in general a case can be made to not use exceptions for flow control, here it hardly counts as such.

I'd probably wrap it in a function, like so

```
public static String getPackageForClass(String className, String... packageNames) {
    for (String packageName : packageNames) {
        try {
            Class.forName(packageName + className);
            return packageName;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

or return the class directly, if you so wish

```
public static Class getPackageForClass(String className, String... packageNames) {
    for (String packageName : packageNames) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(packageName + className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```